# Django render many to many attributes after query, display None

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am using slug to query the model, and render result in HTML.
The code is unable to render actual name of region, it just return **None**

Model

```
class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, unique=True) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Theme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, unique=True) 
    slug = models.SlugField(default="", null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ETF(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=False, db_index=True, unique=True) 
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    # many to many
    region = models.ManyToManyField(Region)
    theme = models.ManyToManyField(Theme)
```

views.py

```
def theme_etf(request, slug): # render ETFs with theme filter   
    filtered_results = ETF.objects.filter(theme__slug=slug) 
    return render(request, "etf/list_etf.html", {
        "ETFs": filtered_results   
    })
```

Part of list_etf.html

```
{% for ETF in ETFs %}            
  <tr>          
      <td>{{ ETF.ticker }}</td>
      <td>{{ ETF.full_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ ETF.region.name }}</td>  # What should I use in this line
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The code is unable to render actual name of region, it just return None
Result

- Ticker, Name, Region
- ARKF, ARK Fintech Innovation ETF, **None**
- ARKK, ARK Innovation ETF, **None**
- KEJI, Global X China Innovation, **None**

I would like to have this:

- Ticker, Name, Region
- ARKF, ARK Fintech Innovation ETF, **Global**
- ARKK, ARK Innovation ETF, **Global**
- KEJI, Global X China Innovation, **China**

I have the information in the database. I have checked it in admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can an ETF have multiple regions as implied by your database design?  If it does not I would suggest you use `ForeignKey` instead.

You are accessing the region field as if it were a `ForeignKey`.
In your database design you need to iterate over the objects saved in the `ManyToManyField` using `.all`.

```
{% for ETF in ETFs %}            
  <tr>          
      <td>{{ ETF.ticker }}</td>
      <td>{{ ETF.full_name }}</td>
      <td>{% for region in ETF.region.all %}{{ region.name }}{%endfor%}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you for the help! I am still figuring out how to structure the data so I will use manytomany for now.

Comment: I'm happy I could help! As a tip I would avoid using m2m fields if not absolutely necessary because there are special problems you will encounter when using .set(), .add(), etc. but I'm confident you'll figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have *many-to-many* relationship, you cannot simply have single values. So, you have to list values.

```
{% for ETF in ETFs %}            
  <tr>          
      <td>{{ ETF.ticker }}</td>
      <td>{{ ETF.full_name }}</td>
      <td>
          <ol>
              {% for region in ETF.region %}
                  <li>{{region.name}}</li>
              {% endfor %} 
          </ol>
      </td> 
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```